# Same yet different Y axis?

Tags: modeling

Iv just found an issue where 2 vertices are on the same Y location yet they are not in the same Y location. And this isn't just me being stupid I have a straight line of vertices along a Y axis yet when I typed the location of the Y axis for that vertices it wasn't the same as the others I had made. I don't see the logic in this
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Are there any modifiers on your object? Shapekeys? Animations? Hooks? Does it have any weird transforms or any other thing that me be distorting its shape